# Regex Ignore Proceeding Words

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regex expression that starts with a certain word and ignores any other same proceeding words.

For example, if my string starts with the word "dog" and ends with "fish", how do I ignore any proceeding "dog" words and only match the last one?

**dog cat fish**

<strike>dog</strike> **dog cat fish** <- ignore first word "dog" and match second "dog" word.

<strike>dog</strike> <strike>dog</strike> **dog cat fish** <- ignore first and second "dog" words and match third "dog" word.

Comment: Is it possible you would have a string such as `dog dog dog cat fish dog dog fish cat`?

Comment: What are the constraints on the word at the start which may or may not repeat? e.g. Is it always 3 letters? Is it a word in a dictionary? (How would you resolve Do from Dog?) Is it always "dog"?

Answer (score 3):

The following `regex` works:

`(\b\w+\b |\b\w+\b$)(?!\1)` with the `m` and `g` flags enabled

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/dW9fP5

As per your new request:

`(\b\w+\b|\b\w+\b$)(?!\1)` with the `m` and `g` flags enabled

Comment: This also works: `(\b\w+) (?!\1).*`. http://regex101.com/r/uM9zH7. Or more precisely: `(\b\w+) (?!\1)(?:\w+ )*\w+$`: http://regex101.com/r/jM1zY2

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick response! Is there a way that I could get this to work without spaces? To ignore any proceeding "dog" words after the last "dog" word?

Such as dogdogcatfish

Comment: @user3525737, What do you mean? Your string is __not__ separated by spaces?

Comment: Yeah, when I posted originally I forgot to mention that they are not separated by spaces (one long string). I appreciate your help so far :D.

Comment: @user3525737, Sure you can, I have updated my answer.

Comment: @user3525737: Please be careful to post all relevant information in your original question. This "Sixth Sense" kind of question (twist at the end that changes everything) can be pretty frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

To strip out space separated duplicates:

*<s>dog dog</s> dog <s>cat</s> cat fish*:

`(?>(\w+) (?=\1\b))+`

test at: [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/rL7fA5), [eval.in](https://eval.in/135677) (if php)

Using a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to check if match of first parenthesized group is ahead (preceded by a space).

---

To match duplicates only at string start, add the `^` [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) at the beginning:

*<s>dog dog</s> dog cat cat fish*

`^(?>(\w+) (?=\1\b))+`

[test at regex101](http://regex101.com/r/qF5oH0)

---

**EDIT**: Question has obviously changed to matching consecutive character sequences in one long string without spaces. Pattern modified a bit to strip out sequences of at least 3 characters at start:

<s>dogdog</s>dogcatcatfish

`^(?>(\w{3,})(?=\1))+`

[test at regex101](http://regex101.com/r/mD7tW9)

---

Replace with empty string `""`

[Regex FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3110638)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple (literal) pattern:

```
.*(dog)
```

Replace Pattern:

```
\1
```

Not the most exciting, but might as well show it. The target word in parentheses sets to match group `\1`

example: http://regex101.com/r/yU6xO8